# How to show fully transparent system bars by swiping in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, uinavigationbar, swipe, statusbar

I need my fully transparent system bars to show by swiping and then hide. Now it is hidden when the app starts
[image].

But after swiping it doesn't hide.

[image]

If I use

```
val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity
with(WindowCompat.getInsetsController(activity.window, activity.window.decorView)) { systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE }
```

the system bar will have a gray tint.

[image]

I need absolutely transparent bar without any shades... Please help!

The code

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
setContent {
            Puzzle_QuestTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
                    systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(color = Transparent)
                    systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(color =Transparent,darkIcons = false)
                    systemUiController.isNavigationBarContrastEnforced = false
                    systemUiController.isNavigationBarVisible = false
                    systemUiController.isSystemBarsVisible = false
                    systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = false
                    PuzzleQuestApp()
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, though not an expert on Compose, but can you add screenshots of the issue. I can check.

Comment: Hi! I need the status bar to hide after a while after the swipe.

Comment: Got it, however the code works for me. Status bar shows for a while when swiped on top, and then disappears. The piece of code which helps for this: 
val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity
                    with(WindowCompat.getInsetsController(activity.window, activity.window.decorView)) {
                        systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
                    }
Tested on Pixel 3a, API 34 emulator.

Comment: If I remove this code, then it stays as you mentioned. Can you check on other devices as well. Also, try removing the method call PuzzleQuestApp() and observe the behaviour. Since this works fine with a sample application, it seems to be some issue with your application code.

Comment: If I use your code the system bar will have a gray tint. I added a screenshot. I need absolutely transparent bar without any shades. That is why I use systemUiController and isNavigationBarContrastEnforced = false

Comment: You have customize the status bar from ```Theme.kt``` file where the statubar color and other configuration take place

Answer (score 0):

after setting systemBarsBehavior

```
setContent {
    Puzzle_QuestTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ) {
            val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
            val window = LocalContext.current.window

            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                val controller = WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView)
                controller.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
                controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            }

            systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(color = Color.Transparent)
            systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(color = Color.Transparent, darkIcons = false)
            systemUiController.isNavigationBarContrastEnforced = false

            PuzzleQuestApp()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not write val window = LocalContext.current.window inside setContent block, we already have a window inside fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {... but even with this window, the code still returns a status bar with gray shadow.